# Install packages during uck Ubuntu customization

Tags: uck

I am following the steps from [this website](https://peteris.rocks/blog/customize-ubuntu-desktop-live-cd-usb/) to customize my Ubuntu image. After unpacking the clean .iso I add some files to the "remaster" and also I would like to install some apps (wireshark for example), so when the systems boots with the custom image, there is no need to install anything. I run the following script:

```
sudo uck-remaster-clean
sudo uck-remaster-unpack-iso my.iso
sudo uck-remaster-unpack-rootfs

// .. add desired files to the remaster
sudo apt-get install wireshark

sudo uck-remaster-pack-rootfs -c
sudo uck-remaster-pack-iso -g myNew.iso
```

However, wireshark is installed on the machine on which I am running the script, not in the remaster-root system. What do I need to modify in the script above to have the apps installed on the unpacked ISO? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to chroot into your remaster-root-system. you forgot to run one command.

```
sudo uck-remaster-chroot-rootfs
```

Comment: I assume this line comes before `sudo apt-get`? Do I have to `chroot` again after installing updates and/or apps?

Comment: Yeah this has to be run before `apt-get`. It is actually there in the website you linked. I don't really have experience with this particular method but you should not need to chroot again. you may have to run `exit` but again I am not sure if that is needed in your case

Comment: I almost got it to work as needed. Once I call `chroot` it changes the prompt to `root@me-VirtualBox:/#` and stays there. So I have to manually call `apt-get` stuff and then `exit` when finished. Then, when I call `exit`, the script continues to execute after the `chroot` line. Is there a way to make apt-get calls automatically from a script?

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/551361/399217. It should do what you want. maybe create another script with all the apt-get commands and place it whithin your chroot environment. then it may be possible to run `sudo uck-remaster-chroot-rootfs ./chroot.sh`. If that does not work, you may need to specify the directory containing your the environment before the script itself. maybe something like `sudo uck-remster-chroot-rootfs <directory> ./chroot.sh`