# Executing a script with chroot; permission denied

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, chroot

I want a script to execute a few commands in chroot. So, like this answer proposed [scripting chroot, how to?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551195/scripting-chroot-how-to) I added the following part in my script, creating a .sh file with the commands I want it to execute.

```
cat <<EOF >/mnt/grubscript.sh
#!/bin/bash
cp /proc/mounts /etc/mtab
grub-install /dev/vdb
grub-install --recheck /dev/vdb
EOF

chroot /mnt ./grubscript.sh
```

This generates the following error:

```
chroot: failed to run command ‘./script.sh’: Permission denied
```

I tried `chmod 777` and `chmod +x` but that doesn't work. The file has been created right, and cannot be executed manually from chroot as well.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu. So is there a `/bin/bash` (inside the chroot) ... or rather `/mnt/bin/bash` (looking from the outside) and is it executable? And yes, the way you attempt to run it, you need to make the script executable. But using a relative path seems odd. You may want to lose that `.`, i.e. `chroot /mnt /grubscript.sh` ... because otherwise you rely on the current working directory inside the chroot.

Comment: @0xC0000022L  Hi, thanks! I deleted the . from the script; no success. Running it by chroot /mnt and then /bin/bash grubscript.sh does work

Comment: for starters you should add an answer, if you found the answer. However, the solution sort of suggests that I wasn't too far off. Your command line would _now_ work no matter if the script had the `x` bit set or not (for file mode), but you claimed you had made it executable. Which is odd. There's some detail, some puzzle piece, you forgot to mention. As it stands this makes no sense. If you answer by yourself, I'll remove my question (or hopefully someone else will, in case I forget).

Answer (score 0):

The inquirer solved it by changing

```
chroot /mnt ./grubscript.sh
```

to:

```
chroot /mnt /bin/bash grubscript.sh
```